# Oracle - best way to use XLSX data directly, not using Apache POI

Tags: excel, oracle, csv, jdbc

In Oracle 12

Is there a quick way you can template how to import XLSX files into Oracle directly?

I can use say apache POI to load it to a temporary java transfer object that gets sent to turn into jdbc/Sql in some fancy way. But it's slow as heck.

There is Sql Developer where you can import CSV. And other tools for CSV.

But what about xlsx spreadsheets from Microsoft Excel? Is there something that can import sheets, columns, formats, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to convert your Excel file from an xls file to a csv file and then you can use an Oracle external table.

Comment: yeah that's what we ended up doing